# SSRS Header not formatted

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Sorry for bad english. We use Sql Server Reporting service (SSRS) and there is a problem with the header

[image]

It seems that this web section is unable to fetch the required CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a load balancer or redirector or Host header values or FQDNs?

Basically, the URL in the browser does not match what SSRS thinks the URL is, based on it's

You will need to set ReportServerUrl in the [RSWebApplication Configuration File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155878(SQL.90).aspx)
And probabky UrlRoot in the [RSReportServer Configuration File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273(SQL.90).aspx) too

[A blog entry, easier to read then BOL](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2007/01/26/hosting-reporting-services-on-a-fully-qualified-domain-name-fqdn.aspx)